# Rails - find_by column other than "id" results in "null"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Been trying to get this working for the past several hours, I'm probably over looking something quite simple. Basically I have a "posts" model, and one of the columns I have created is named `guid`, which is just a user definable field that gets saved to the database.

I'm looking to `find_by` the `guid` instead of the default `id`.

Of course I've tried `@post = Post.find_by_guid(params[:guid])` in my posts controller `show` action, but when I attempt to call it from the url (ex: mysite/post/53), in the server console it says `guid is NULL`

Webrick Console:

```
Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"53"}
  Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."guid" IS NULL LIMIT 1
....
```

Comment: How are you submitting the `guid` value from the client? Only `id` is present in the parameters, so there's nothing the controller can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the route is

```
get "/posts/:id"
```

Then you will its the id that is going to be placed in the params which you can see in the output. So use params[:id]

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
```

You should change your route if you are passing a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier):

```
get "posts/:guid" ...
```

Hit the url "posts/21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D"

And then in the controller:

```
@post = Post.find_by guid: params[:guid]
```

Rails passes instance variables (any variable starting with @) set in the controller to the views.
Referencing instance variables in the view that the controller did not set will return nil, which does not have any of the methods you are going to call on it, hence the "No method" errors.

Any time you run into trouble, check your assumptions at the console. I recommend using [Pry](http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails). Using Pry (calling "binding.pry" in your code) you can actually stop the execution at any point and look around. That way you never have to guess.

Comment: Only problem I'm finding is when I add a route for guid and then replace the find to find_by guid: .... the views no longer work because I guess guid can't reference any of the other fields such as id could. For example, <%= @post.name %> which worked with id is now giving a No Method error for name

Comment: I expanded the answer and fixed up the code. If you need more info leave another comment and I can clarify more.

Answer (score 0):

The `find_by_[column]` method is deprecated.

Use the following syntax: `find_by guid: params[:guid]`

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters hash does not contain a `:guid` key. If you were to use `mysite/post/53?guid=SOMETHING` then you will see a `:guid` key in `params`.

Do you want the 53 in this example to be the GUID parameter? There are ways to change the Rails routes to get that parameter to be `guid` instead of `id`, but if 53 is the GUID, you can always go:

```
Post.find(:guid => params[:id]).first
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got "unknown key: guid" with this